# One line If statement in Razor not working

Tags: blazor, razor-pages

This statement outputs the the HTML exactly, my intent is for it the be rendered as HTML.

```
<td>@(part.IsVocal ? "<span class='badge bg-success'>Yes</span>" : "<span class='badge bg-danger'>No</span>") / 
    @(part.IsInstrumental ? "<span class='badge bg-success'>Yes</span>" : "<span class='badge bg-danger'>No</span>")</td>
```

It renders in the browser as:

```
<td>
    "<span...."
    " / "
    "<span...."
</td>
```

So it's rendering them as strings, rather then code.

Comment: Q: Are you getting any errors or warnings? In either/both MSVS (compile time) or Chrome Developer Tools?  Q: Assuming your page is rendered, have you tried "View Element" in Chrome Developer Tools?  What is being rendered from Blazor to the web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MarkupString like ther

```
<td>@(part.IsVocal ? (MarkupString)"<span class='badge bg-success'>Yes</span>" : (MarkupString)"<span class='badge bg-danger'>No</span>") / 
    @(part.IsInstrumental ? (MarkupString)"<span class='badge bg-success'>Yes</span>" : (MarkupString)"<span class='badge bg-danger'>No</span>")</td>
```

Note that you may use MarkupString in various ways, including getting MarkupString values from properties. You may make your code above shorter and compactor... I just answered your question...

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do that is:

```
@if(part.IsVocal)
{
    <span class='badge bg-success'>Yes</span>
}
else
{
    <span class='badge bg-danger'>No</span>
}
```

and so on..

Comment: I don't think this is the right way... Just another way. But alas, the OP did not ask for the right way, but rather how to do that `One line If statement`, meaning the conditional operator.

Comment: I agree, but I think it's a far more readable way.  using the ? : ; might be precise, but it's almost illegible!  It often works well in code, but Razor ????

Comment: Using if else instead of using ternary operator makes code more manageable I think